# Fancybox and Tinymce_gzip

Tags: fancybox, tinymce

I have a problem with the fancy box.
My problem is this.

A have a website in Ajax. All the page is in Ajax and i use fancy box for displaying some information.
It is working every time until i open a tinymce editor. I use tinymce GZIP.

I trying shut down tinymce but still doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".grayDClr").fancybox({
beforeShow: function () { try{
for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++) {
tinyMCE.EditorManager.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", true, tinymce.editors[i].id);
}
}catch(err) {alert(err)} },
openEffect : 'none',
closeEffect : 'none',
maxWidth : 831,
minHeight : 0,
minWidth : 500,
autoSize : true,
fitToView : true,
margin : 40,
padding : [15, 15, 45, 15],
afterShow : function() {}
});
});
```

Comment: how do you shutdown tinymce? try to log tinymce.editor[0] to console and tell me what you get

Comment: we try to clsoe with : tinyMCE.EditorManager.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", true, tinymce.editors[i].id); and error console gives as below mentioned--  "ypeError: tinymce.editor is undefined"

Comment: @thariama we try to clsoe with : tinyMCE.EditorManager.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", true, tinymce.editors[i].id); and error console gives as below mentioned-- "ypeError: tinymce.editor is undefined"

Comment: this is good, because it shows that the editor instance is really shut down. can you show me the exact point of time when you initialize the tinymce editor? does it work the first time, but not the second?

Comment: Thanks @Thariama-- but if its close why then we can not properly open fancy box?--- as what happens is that IF I refresh the page I can then ope fancy box with the content inside it-.-. but if I do not refresh it and he fancy box does NOT open at all - does not get executed when I click on the link to view content I created with the tinyMce

Comment: +1 for live  example....hmm, works fine using the latest FireFox. does it happen with a special browser?

Comment: @Thariama FF 15 is my version -- but it does not work-- If I go to editor and try toa dd something there--- and back to home page what I get when trying to open fancy box with content inside is for example http://www.yodito.com/html/view-note.php?id=1938  as html page and that should open inside the Fancy box---  if I the refresh the page, then it works, fancy box shows as popup as it should.

Comment: hmm, i get the error tinymce is not defined. can you load tiny_mce_dev.js on yoour main page?

Comment: Will do that right away-- we are  taking and adding to see what causes this error, that is why also UI is messy now, dont mind that---

Comment: @Thariama  thanks-- check now-- we added tinymce back to the page-- as you can see it works if we refresh the page, if we come from edigtor tinymce back to home page and first time the fancy box does not open-- could it be the cache for tinymcw GZIP--- -- cna you have a look now? thanks appreciated it :)

Comment: @Thariama would you be able to check our site again and inspect our code from the editor an closing it and bvack to Home page?-- something is maybe left  out--  or tinymce gzip or cache  -- what do you think?

Comment: do i understand you correctly that you want to get a tinymce editor if the user clicks on an entry from the list? in my browser a new page gets loaded, but no fanybox

Comment: yes1 that is the issue--- we want to open fancy box with that content from the the list--- but it does not open in fancy box, it only opens as a htmp page, but if we refresh the page it open inside fancy box.  The issue happens ONLY when we come from tinymce to Home page, it seems it does not properly closes!!! and we need to refresh  manually the page to avoid this issue..

Comment: it looks indeed like tinymce does not propperly close, even though it seems to be closed. i get that error  

$('.contactBox [ydt-id="a717ae1aa109e4e8cad54e334e616054"]').prop("width",'');  can you eliminate this?

Comment: @Thariama Thanks---- we found the issue-- it seems there was a interference with the tinyMce GZIP file-- and we remove it and no its works-- so solution was to open and close tinymce with no gzip version file used, and same time we updated to latest TinyMce version--- seems fine now-- an big thanks for your help in debugging this :)